# Microsoft Excel to forecast when a value is hit

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a coder, not a statistician, and reading the blogs on LINEST, FORECAST, TREND are all baffling to me.

I'm pretty sure I want to use FORECAST, and from my reading this is how it is used:

= FORECAST (New X Value, Known Y values, Known X values)

So here's my data:

```
1/1/2017 10,000
1/2/2017 12,000
1/5/2017 17,000
1/6/2017 18,000
```

I have dates on my x-axis and values on the y-axis. The question I'm trying to answer is when will the value be n, say 30,000.

We can assume that my data should be forecast linearly. I can also say that it will never go down, but I don't think that that matters

The FORECAST help says that it wants an x as the first parameter, so it is going to tell me for a particular X what my value will be. So I put this in:

```
=FORECAST(1/10/2017,B33:B36,A33:A36)
```

and get this back

```
24,764
```

And that's certainly a plausible number. So how do I get X out for a given Y?

Comment: good catch, question is edited.

Comment: I don't think such a function would exist. You can use `SLOPE` and `INTERCEPT` functions to get the parameters of your estimated line, then solve it for y. (e.g. your line will be y=a*x+b, then your desired x will be something like: `(y-INTERCEPT(...))/SLOPE(...)`)

Comment: I've done this before. Sadly, I didn't save my code when I left the position. I tracked when we'd run out of space on storage servers, when printer ongoing costs would reach a given amount, etc. I think you just need to flip your X and Y axes. It's not what the value will be at a given date, but WHEN it will be when the value is a given amount.

Comment: @music2myear, that's the most direct approach.  Post an answer?

Comment: Oh that's interesting, it means the data will look weird but yeah, the answer should be correct then!

Comment: If you're looking at visualizing the data too, run it twice, once for the pretty chart, and once for the prediction report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to flip your X and Y axes.

Currently you are looking at the what the value will be on a given date, but flipping the axes will show you the date it will reach a given value, essentially giving you a prediction.

So let's say your target value is 50,000. Use the formula:

```
=FORECAST(50000,A33:A36,B33:B36)
```

You may need to format the cell as Date, otherwise you'll get a big number in there.

In this case, this formula on that data told me you'd reach 50,000 on the 25th of January of this year. Yesterday.